# PhotoEditorSDK change default control on editor start

Tags: javascript, json, editor, photoeditorsdk

In the DesktopUI I have the configuration files with this parameters.

```
tools: ['transform', 'adjustments', 'text', 'overlay', 'filter']
controlsOrder: [['adjustments', 'filter', 'overlay'], ['transform', 'text']]
```

And as a default the filter tab shows up when I create the editor.

Is there any way to set the adjustments tab as a default at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not documented, as we don't support `transform` as the initial control, but you could try setting `options.editor.defaultControl` to `adjustments`.